# Backbonejs - return different model depending on type attribute

Tags: backbone.js, superclass

I have a main model called ItemModel that on fetch returns an attribute called "type" among others. The type can be Article, Image, Video, etc.
Is there a way to return a different model (ArticleModel, ImageModel..) depending on the type?

The implementation would be:

```
var itemModel = new ItemModel();
itemModel.fetch();
itemModel.on("sync", this.getModel, this);
this.getModel = function(model) {
    console.log(model.get("type")) // returns "Article";
    console.log(model instanceof ArticleModel); // returns true and gets all the properties/methods of ArticleModel
}
```

I tried doing

```
//ItemModel
...parse: function(data) {
    _.extend(this.constructor.prototype, ArticleModel.prototype);
    return data;
}
```

but that doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Thank you

Comment: Do you really need different kinds of models in a single collection? Keep in mind that a model's attributes can vary model-to-model so the attributes and the Model aren't tightly bound.

Comment: Hey, yes, in this case each of my models have a lots of additional logic, so it would be hard to maintain